# Web scraping on silverlight 4 page

Tags: silverlight, selenium, web-scraping, silverlight-4.0

There is a web page with a silver light application embedded and I want to scrape it. I wonder if there is a web scraping solution or browser automation solution (or any trick/hack) that supports silverlight in either C#, Java or Python.

I am currently trying [silvernium](https://code.google.com/p/silverlight-selenium/) but it is quite outdated project and doesn't seem to work properly with silverlight 4.

Here is some of the html information of the SL object in the page:

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">

<param name="source" value="PATH/WebSilverlight.xap"/>
<param name="onerror" value="onSilverlightError"/>
<param name="background" value="white"/>
<param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50524.0"/>
<param name="autoUpgrade" value="true"/>
<param name="windowless" value="true"/>
<param name="enableautozoom" value="true"/>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I implemented a workaround using the computer vision based technology [SikuliX](http://www.sikulix.com/) and getting a printed PDF out of the Silverlight web app like normal normal user would to get the information. Here is an [script](https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX-2014/blob/master/StuffContainer/testScripts/testRobot/testRun.sikuli/testRun.py) that shows how to run this along with Selenium.

Another alternative is to hack the requests and keep the session alive while navigating to the information you need using either [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/), [abot](https://github.com/sjdirect/abot), [crawler4j](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j) or any other similar technology.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked successfully with [Telerik testing framework](http://www.telerik.com/teststudio/testing-framework) for an

> automation solution that supports silverlight in C#

It's free and once you get to used to it - very easy, because of the rich API and the cross-browser compatibility. Maybe the trickiest part is to initially config the tests.

Simple example:

```
Settings mySettings = new Settings();
mySettings.Web.DefaultBrowser = BrowserType.InternetExplorer;
Manager myManager = new Manager(mySettings);
myManager.Start();    
myManager.LaunchNewBrowser();

myManager.ActiveBrowser.NavigateTo("http://www.example.com");

Element mybtn = myManager.ActiveBrowser.Find.ByTagIndex("input", 3);
myManager.ActiveBrowser.Actions.Click(mybtn);

myManager.Dispose();
```

A good addition to it is the Windows [Inspect tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx). It'll enable you to select any UI element and view the element's accessibility data in some tricky cases.

*Update:*

I've searched some helpful documentation links that I've used back in the days. Look at [Getting started](http://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/testing-framework/write-tests-in-code/silverlight-wpf-automation-wtc/silverlight-ui-automation) with Silverlight UI Automation and [Locating elements](http://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/testing-framework/write-tests-in-code/silverlight-wpf-automation-wtc/locating-elements).

Comment: Sounds promising , will try it once I get my hands on a Windows machine today, or its there a way to try this in osx?

Comment: unfortunately, this technology wasn't suited for the requirements of the production environment the program was supposed to run but it was great to know about it, thanks again.